# WP_Query returns only one post

Tags: wordpress, while-loop

My loop returns only one post instead all. I going through it 4th time and i do not see any reason why it act like that. Thank you for all your help.

`localStorage` has been cleaned, cache also - and yeah i have more then one post published in this category :)

```
function rtf_custom_grid( ) {


  $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'apartamenty',
      'post_per_page' => -1,
      'nopaging' => true,
      'order' => 'date',
      'orderby' => 'DESC'
    );

  $rtf_query = new WP_Query ( $args );

  while($rtf_query->have_posts() ) : $rtf_query->the_post();
  $cena_1 = get_field('cena_1');
  $cena_2 = get_field('cena_2');
  $short_dec = get_field('short_desc');

  $output = '<div class="single-apartament">';

    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :

    $output .= '<div class="rtf-apartament-thumbnail">';
    $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_id(), 'large') . '</a></div>';

    endif;

    $output .= '<div class="rtf-apartament-content">';
    $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() .'" class="apartament-ttile">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
    $output .= '<div class="rtf-apartament-excerpt">' . $short_dec . '</div>';

    $output .= '<div class="rtf-apartament-prize">';
    $output .= '<span>' . $cena_1 . ' / ' . $cena_2 . '</span></div>';

    $output .= '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'" class="apartament-readmore">Zobacz</a></div></div></div>';

  endwhile;

  wp_reset_query();
  return $output;
}

add_shortcode('apartamenty', 'rtf_custom_grid');
```

Comment: Change `$output = '<div class="single-apartament">';`  to `$output .= '<div class="single-apartament">';` . It was overwriting old content of $output in while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$output = ' <div class="single-apartament"> ';
```

the above line is overwriting the previous content in the variable. So its showing only the last post.

Solution :

```
 $output.= '<div class="single-apartament">';
```

This will append the html code into the variable instead of overwriting it.

Hope it works for you

Comment: @Ganga what's wrong in my solution in comment? (-_-')

Comment: Thant was actually my mistake - i made one small update in code meanwhile and its why your solution did not worked. When second person answered the same i rewind changes and tried again.

Comment: Hmm actually there is one more problem, now it goes to 4 posts and stops. No clue why .

Comment: 'post_per_page' should be 'posts_per_page' , so 's' is missing in argument index.